# How to iterate using the timestamp from an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux.`. Here I have an response which is like ,

```
{
        "content": [{
            "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075051"
            "createdAt": 12345677,,
            "Name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075051"
            "createdAt": 12235677,
        },
        {
            "id": "5b7d4a566c5f0507501051"
            "createdAt": 123675677,
        }]
    }
```

Now, with this data I am creating a table which looks like,

```
{this.props.data && this.props.data.content && this.props.data.content.length > 0 && this.props.data.content.map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td className="font-weight-bold wc-30">{key + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.Name}</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
```

Now, I do have that `createdAt` which is the `timeStamp`. So, I want to render this table in `ascending order`. Like, which ever is created at latest will be at the first place .

So, I tried with one

```
const sortedList = this.props.data.sort((a, b) => b.createdDate - a.createdDate);
```

But, I was not getting there. So, Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: What date format are you using ?

Comment: use createAt instead of createdDate in sort method comparision

Answer (score 2):

Your list doesn't have any createdDate defined. Try sorting by createdAt.

like this:

```js
let json = [{
    id: "5b7d4a566c5fd005075051",
    createdAt: 12345677,
    Name: "abc"
  },
  {
    id: "5b7d4a566c5fd005075051",
    createdAt: 12235677,
  },
  {
    id: "5b7d4a566c5f0507501051",
    createdAt: 123675677,
  }
]


const output = json.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.createdAt - a.createdAt
})
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json.sort((a, b) => { return a.createdAt - b.createdAt })
```

a-b not b-a.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code, using sort() func

```
import React from "react";

var x = {
        "content": [{
            "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075051",
            "createdAt": 12345677,
            "Name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075051",
            "createdAt": 12235677,
            "Name": "d"
        },
        {
            "id": "5b7d4a566c5f0507501051",
            "createdAt": 123675677,
            "Name": "e"
        }]
    };
var y = x.content.sort((a,b)=>{
    return a.createdAt-b.createdAt
})

class Main extends React.Component {

render(){
    return(
        <table>
        <tbody>
                {y.map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td className="font-weight-bold wc-30">{key + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.Name}</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}

        </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
}


export default Main;
```

Comment: The way I used it is like {this.props.jobList && this.props.jobList.content && this.props.jobList.content.length > 0 && this.props.jobList.content.sort((a, b) => b.createdDate - a.createdDate).map((item, key) => {

Comment: Because I want to show the badge which should be there if it is the latest one

Comment: Did you mean to chain .sort().map() ?
Yes, it could.
in your code b.createdDate - a.createdDate, means descending order.

Comment: Yes I mean to chaain

Comment: I want to have whichever is created latest

Comment: if latest, then it's correct to be descending order

Comment: One more thing If I want to show a badge to the latest one then should I use Id thing like if the first one is going to be always going to have an id of 1. so

Comment: the latest one, means the first index right? So, you can just use `key===0&&<td>Your badge</td>`